# How to set onclick event in yii custom radio button?

Tags: radio-button, yii2

This is my Html for custom radio button in yii2

```
<?php
     echo $form->field($ProductShipping, 'id_shipping')->radioList(
          ['1'=>'Free', '2'=>'Pickup','3'=>'Country Wise','4'=>'API'],
              ['item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

               $return = '<label class="radio">';
               $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '">';
               $return .= '<label>' . ucwords($label) . '</label>';
               $return .= '</label>';
               return $return;
             }
           ]
         )->label(false);

?>
```

How to set an onclick event in this custom radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it following way:

```
<?php
     echo $form->field($ProductShipping, 'id_shipping')->radioList(
          ['1'=>'Free', '2'=>'Pickup','3'=>'Country Wise','4'=>'API'],
              ['item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {    
               $return = '<label class="radio">';
               $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '">';
               $return .= '<label>' . ucwords($label) . '</label>';
               $return .= '</label>';
               return $return;
             },
               'onclick' => "alert('test')"
           ]
         )->label(false);

?>
```

Comment: Great, helped me..!!

Comment: In that case if i alert (this.id) it shows div id, how can i select the radio button value??

Comment: use the javascript val() function

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would accept the answer, if it has helped :)